# How to allow all file to accessible from uploads folder through .htaccess setting

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have root directory with files

```
 - api.php
 - .htaccess
 - uploads/
 - uploads/abc.jpg
 - uploads/xyz.jpg
```

I'm writing rest API for the mobile developer ,so I have successfully created number of API listed below

**api.php**

```
function register(){
    //POST Method
    //I can access this API with URL http://example.com/register
}

function login(){
    //POST Method
    //I can access this API with URL http://example.com/login
}

function user(){
    //GET Method
    //I can access this API with URL http://example.com/user
}
```

Now the problem is what user profile image is store in the upload directory i.e (ab.jpg,xyz.jpg) and I can not access it using http://example.com/uploads/abc.jpg

I figure out it is due to `.htaccess` file which I have placed in the root level directory and code inside this file is :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ api.php?rquest=$1 [QSA,NC,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ api.php [QSA,NC,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ api.php [QSA,NC,L]   
</IfModule>
```

I don't know how I can allow uploads folder to access it publicly using .htaccess

Comment: Its because you are rewriting your existent directries to /api.php . Try removing your #2 RewriteCond and rule.

Comment: And replace **!-s** with **!-f** to avoid rewriting of existent files.

Comment: Thanks @starkeen it worked this is what I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this will work. Just add this line to each redirection.

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(jpg|png)$`

[Check .htaccess here](http://htaccess.mwl.be/)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(jpg|png)$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ api.php?rquest=$1 [QSA,NC,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(jpg|png)$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ api.php [QSA,NC,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(jpg|png)$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ api.php [QSA,NC,L]   
</IfModule>
```

Comment: No it now working ,when I replace your code with my code image URL works but API URL not work and when I place both then it not work any thing

Comment: @AmanMaurya Updated my post now you can check again, Do let me know if you got any issue